# How to display mortgage payment with a nested for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, multiple-columns

I am trying to display a table for a mortgage loan program using nested for-loops. The outer loop is controlled by the interest rate as it processes it from the starting rate to the endinging, and the inner loop is controlled by the starting term in years to the ending term in years.
The interest rate is incremented by .25 after every iteration and the year is incremented by 5.

I am having difficulties calculating the payment when more than a single column is generated.

This is the expected output:

```
Interest    15 Years        20 Years        25  Years
 4.000       739.69          605.98          527.84 
 4.250       752.28          619.23          541.74 
 4.500       764.99          632.65          555.83 
 4.750       777.83          646.22          570.12 
 5.000       790.79          659.96          584.59
```

This is my output:

```
Interest
  Rate     15  Years        20  Years        25  Years
 4.000       739.69          739.69          739.69 
 4.250       752.28          752.28          752.28 
 4.500       764.99          764.99          764.99 
 4.750       777.83          777.83          777.83 
 5.000       790.79          790.79          790.79
```

and this is what I have to calculate the loan amount:

```
//startingYear is the first term entered by the user
//ending Year is the last term entered by the user
     displayTableHeader(startingYear, endingYear, startCount, yearCounter);



//sCountaRate is the starting interest rate
// n determines how many time the rate will iterate
        for (int j = sCountRate;j <= n; j++){


//displays first column interest rate
          System.out.printf("\n %1.3f",startRate);


//startCount is the starting year
//ending year is the last term in years entered by user
//yearsCounter determines the amount of time it will increment (5 in this case)
          for (int i = startCount; i <= endingYear;i = i + yearCounter){



//calculates loan payment
            totalPayment = calculateLoanPayment(startRate, loanAmount, startCount); 


            System.out.printf("\t     %.2f ", totalPayment);

          }
//starting interest rate is incremented by .25 after every iteration
          startRate += TF_INCREMENTS;
        }

      }
```

Comment: what language? Java?

Comment: Yes, i am using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it like this:

```
  displayTableHeader(startingYear, endingYear, startingYearDisplay, yearCounter);


        for (int j = sCountRate;j <= n; j++){

          System.out.printf("\n %1.3f",startRate);

          for (int i = startingYear; i <= endingYear;i = i + yearCounter){


            totalPayment = calculateLoanPayment(startRate, loanAmount, startingYearDisplay); 


            System.out.printf("\t%4.2f ", totalPayment);

 //I added this to add 5 every time the inner loop iterates, so it would do the first row.
            startingYearDisplay += 5;

          }
          startRate += TF_INCREMENTS;

//AND this to prevent it of increasing 5 every time a row was printed, so it wont go over the selected amount years.
          startingYearDisplay = startingYear;
        }

      }
```